# All content types missing for users other than UID#1

Tags: users

I am hoping that someone can help me.
I run a network of Drupal websites. They share the same code, but have different databases for each website.

This week, one of the websites began having a serious error -- any user other than me (UID #1) is restricted from seeing all of the content types and therefore cannot add any content, at all.

I've not made any changes to the websites that I am aware of that would cause this to occur. My other websites are all working fine and not having any similar issues.

As UID#1, I can do things normally, but if I masquerade as any other role or user, I am unable to add any content at all. When I mask as one of my higher level users who can see the content types, they are shown a screen that says no custom content types have been created.

I have looked at permissions and everything looks fine. Nothing looks any different than my other websites. I rebuilt the content access permissions and cleared the cache, but that did not help.

I've done some googling to see if I could find any similar issues and while there are a couple instances where content types have disappeared, they are all for earlier versions of Drupal and I assume do not apply to me. I am currently running Drupal 7.41 (just updated today).

Any creative suggestions on where to look next to try to resolve this issue are most appreciated. I'm truly stumped!

Heather

Comment: Did the problems start after updating to 7.41 or even 7.40? Or did you update any other modules in the last week?

Comment: The problems started sometime in the last few days. I just updated to 7.41 from like 7.39 to see if that would help with the issue.

Comment: Another thing to note:
I have a role that provides full content administration, content type administration, etc. When I mask as this role, if I go to add content from the link in the administration menu, I get a page that says "You have not created any content types yet. Go to the content type creation page to add a new content type." but when I (using the same account) go to admin/structure/types, all of the content types are listed.

I've checked the navigation menu, as I know that can mess with them showing up, but its fine. I've rebuilt access permissions. I'm stumped :(

Comment: I suggest you test the role by actually creating a dummy account and logging in to that account rather than masquerade... I've had some issues like that in the past with it

Comment: Thanks longboardnode for the advice.
My user who I was masking as is experiencing the same problem.

This morning I tried removing all add content permissions and re-adding them, thinking perhaps that might reset something, but alas, no luck.

I'm not even sure what module would be affecting it in this way - as I said, I have 25+ additional websites running the exact same system, and have received the exact same updates and do not have the issue. This leads me to think its a problem in the database somehow?

Comment: Yeah, not sure what to make of this... sorry

Comment: Anyone else have any ideas? My only other option is basically rebuilding the whole site from scratch, which is not an ideal situation, obviously. Any assistance is most appreciated!

Comment: btw what are all the access modules you are using?

Comment: I  am using content access and OG access.

Comment: Oops -- sorry -- I need to stop hitting enter! The settings for both are the same as on my other websites (nothing has changed).

They users can still see and even edit content that exists -- they are only restricted from adding new content. I thought it would have something to do with the node module or maybe the menu module, but I can't see anything off about them. Uninstalling and reinstalling either of those modules is basically taking the whole site apart :/

Comment: Hmmm, have you tried using Devel or some similar module to compare user variables and permissions between the offending site and the sites that work weell?

Comment: So I did this over the weekend -- Devel shows that she has access to all content and should have access to the individual nodes.

She can't add any content, nor see she any content types in the node/add screen -- she CAN see the content types listed in admin/structure/type.She does have permission to add, edit and delete all nodes and full content access.

Is it possible to rebuild the user permissions (not the content access permissions)? Could I essentially import and overwrite that table from one of my other installs to this site, since they are clones and should be the same anyway?

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding permissions here: admin/reports/status/rebuild ?

Comment: Yes I did do that. I have also rebuilt the menus using devel as well as now entirely replaced the permissions with ones that are from another clone of the site, just to see if there was something in there that I was missing.

I am totally 100% stumped. All signs point that these users should see the content just fine... and I've not changed any settings myself, so I cannot for the life of me figure out why suddenly no one can add any content :/

Comment: How about creating a new role that is a copy of the troubling role, and see if the new role has access?